Why does my pip installation fail in VScode?
This is what happens when I tried to run command pip:

I tried running ensurepip in VScode and it kept on showing this command line does anyone know why? Or is there any other way to download pip and set it to VScode?
I also tried to download the pip document from curl but it still didn't work and where normally should u put pip document under? it just kept on saying that there was no pip but when I tried to download it it says it already exist but does not execute any pip command

Please don't post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.

You can use python -m pip to access the pip installation associated with the globally installed version of python on your system.
If you wanna access pip globally you gotta add the path to your pip installation to the PATH environment variable, or setup a python virtual environment in your project location and activate that first instead - see How to use virtualenv with Python?.

hello I tried 'python -m pip' already but it just kept on saying the command failed just as previously is there a way that I can move the pip folder into VScode without using the terminal? Because without pip I don't think I can download venv

A nice and efficient way to keep things organized is by using virtual environments. Here is how to do it in VS Code.
Open your project's directory in VSCode
and close all terminals, click on the trashcan icon to kill all the terminals.

Then open a new terminal by doing: ctrl + shift + ~
now inside your project directory type the command:
 python -m venv venv

This should create a virtual environment for your project. You can then tell VSCode to use that environment.
Change the python interpreter in VSCode by doing ctrl + shift + p
and searching for >Python Select Interpreter including the less than sign.

Select .\venv\Scripts\python.exe and reboot the terminal using the trashcan.
Now try to use python -m ensurepip and it should work as intended.
You will have to install all the packages manually unless you're using a requirements.txt file.
